# Google Maps Compose

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a simple map with one marker. The position of the marker is updated every 5000 milliseconds. How can I make the marker move smoothly to the new position? At the moment, it 'jumps' from the first to the second position. I tried with some compose animation but I wasn't able to achive anything

```
val marker1 = rememberMarkerState(key = "1", position = LatLng(10.0, 10.0))
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
LaunchedEffect(key1 = null) {
    scope.launch {
        while (true) {
            marker1.position = LatLng(marker1.position.latitude+0.001, marker1.position.longitude+0.001)
            delay(5000)
        }
    }
}

GoogleMap(
    modifier = modifier,
    cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
    properties = mapProperties,
    uiSettings = uiSettings,
    onMapLoaded = onMapLoaded,
) {
    Marker(
        state = marker1
    )

    content()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I achieved the same by this
Here is the mainactivity code.
LatLngs are from various places in Delhi.
Marker moves smoothly from one place to another. You can modify the code according to your needs

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        val latLngList: List<LatLng> = listOf(
            LatLng(28.6139, 77.2090),
            LatLng(28.7041, 77.1025),
            LatLng(28.6134, 77.2405),
            LatLng(28.5721, 77.2325),
            LatLng(28.6999, 77.1090),
            LatLng(28.6135, 77.0728),
            LatLng(28.6517, 77.2219),
            LatLng(28.6149, 77.2274),
            LatLng(28.6737, 77.4375),
            LatLng(28.6139, 77.2568)
        )

        var currentIndex by rememberSaveable { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
        var markerPosition by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(latLngList[currentIndex]) }
        MapAppTheme {
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            ) {
                val delhi = LatLng(28.6139, 77.2090)
                val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
                    position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(delhi, 20f)
                }

                val markerState = rememberMarkerState("marker1")


                GoogleMap(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,

                    onMapLoaded = {
                        markerState.position = delhi

                    }
                ) {
                    Marker(
                        state = markerState,
                        icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA),
                        draggable = true,
                    )
                }

                LaunchedEffect(currentIndex) {
                    while (currentIndex < latLngList.size - 1) {
                        val startPosition = markerPosition
                        val endPosition = latLngList[currentIndex + 1]
                        val totalSteps = 10000
                        val duration = 50000L
                        val stepDuration = duration / totalSteps

                        for (step in 0 until totalSteps) {
                            val fraction = step.toFloat() / totalSteps
                            val intermediatePosition = LatLng(
                                startPosition.latitude + (endPosition.latitude - startPosition.latitude) * fraction,
                                startPosition.longitude + (endPosition.longitude - startPosition.longitude) * fraction
                            )
                            markerPosition = intermediatePosition
                            delay(stepDuration)
                        }

                        currentIndex++
                    }
                }


                cameraPositionState.position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(
                    LatLng(
                        markerPosition.latitude,
                        markerPosition.longitude
                    ), 16f
                )

                markerState.position = markerPosition
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}